# Flex-layout semi-fixed position

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have an issue concerning angular's flex-layout. 
Basically I have two divs with fxFlex containing a mat-card each, and I want the right mat-card to be vertically fixed (as shown in the pictures) i.e. I still want the (horisontal)responsive behaviour when resizing the window, but fixed vertically.

Does anyone know how this behaviour can be achieved?

```
<div fxFlex>
  <mat-card><mat-card>
</div>
<div fxFlex="50">
  <mat-card><mat-card>
</div>
```

[image: InitialState]

[image: CurrentBehavior]

[image: WantedBehavior]

Comment: Hmm you should add a scroll to the part you want to be scrolled and not both parts. Or use `onscroll=` on the div and do it programmatic.

Comment: flex-layout is not meant to handle scroll-fixed elements. Its a helper to use css-flexbox in a programmatic way.

Comment: ahh nice! Thank you! This worked, but it created an (ugly) scrollbar in the middle, but decided to just hide it with ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Swoox I found a solution:

```
<div fxFlex style="overflow: scroll">
  <mat-card><mat-card>
</div>
<div fxFlex="50">
  <mat-card><mat-card>
</div>
```

To hide generated scrollbar in css (Chrome):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
```